# How to test actions that expect an uploaded file in Play Framework (version 2.0, using Scala)?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, functional-testing

The [Writing functional tests](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFunctionalTest) portion of the documentation is pretty skimpy and lacks details on submitting mock form values completely.  I somehow (can't remember how/where) determined you can submit basic form values (mocking a POST request) by passing a `Map` to `FakeRequest` like so:

```
val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(POST, "/path/to/test", FakeHeaders(),
                                Map("postedVariable" -> Seq("and a value"))))
```

However, that doesn't seem to allow for the case of an "uploaded" file.

Comment: You can find a couple of hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890381/test-multipartformdata-in-play-2-0-fakerequest

Comment: Be awesome to see this updated for Play 2.1.x

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our file upload tests look something like this:

```
val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new java.io.File("/tmp/the.file"))
val part = FilePart[TemporaryFile](key = "image", filename = "the.file", contentType = Some("image/jpeg"), ref = tempFile)
val formData = MultipartFormData(dataParts = Map(), files = Seq(part), badParts = Seq(), missingFileParts = Seq())
val result = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(POST, "/path/to/test", FakeHeaders(), formData))
```

where `"image"` is the name of the HTML form element you expect to find the file contents in.

If you are using `BodyParsers.maxLength` to limit the size of uploads, you can replace `formData` with `Right(formData)`

Comment: That's what I needed! Except one problem: When constructing the `FakeRequest`, I had to remove the `Right` wrapper that you had around `formData`; thus, the last line should be: `val result = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(POST, "/path/to/test", FakeHeaders(), formData))`

Comment: And I also want to note that the `key` parameter for the `FilePart` should be the name that your HTML form's file input uses.

Comment: Sorry, the `Right` wrapper was because we use `BodyParsers.maxLength` to limit the size of uploads.  I forgot to strip that out when building my example.