# How to test REST API multiple file upload with sigoden apitest?

Tags: java, rest, testing, playframework

I have defined a file upload method which supports multiple files upload:

```
 public static Result upload() {
   MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
   FilePart file1 = body.getFile("filePart1");
   FilePart file2 = body.getFile("filePart2");
   .....
   .....
 }
```

I would like to test this REST API and I am not sure how to do it.

Could someone help me on how to test it?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352618/how-to-test-actions-that-expect-an-uploaded-file-in-play-framework-version-2-0

Comment: no..it doesn't help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>download the POSTMAN plugin from chrome webstore</strike>

[its going to be depercated from webstore better to download from this link](https://www.getpostman.com/)

[image: send the file to test multiple file upload]

Comment: Thanks. Do we have an equivalent free tool for PC and free plugin in firefox?

Comment: HttpRequester addons  comes for mozilla

Answer (score 1):

In-case if you want to do the automated test from the build, please follow as below.

(I prefer automated test), which can be done with RestAssured as follows.

```
     io.restassured.RestAssured.given()
            .multiPart("filePart1", "filename1.txt", file1, FILE_TYPE)
            .multiPart("filePart2", "filename2.txt", file2, FILE_TYPE)
            .expect()
            .when()
            .post("/api/files")
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)
```

If you are in springframework, which can be done simpler as mentioned in [this blog (code a line)](https://codealine.wordpress.com/2018/01/19/how-to-test-file-upload-rest-api/)

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with apitest

```
{
  test3: { @describe('test multi-part')
    req: {
      url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        'content-type': "multipart/form-data",
      },
      body: {
        filePart1: "filename1.txt", @file
        filePart2: "filename2.txt", @file
      }
    },
    res: {
      status: 200
    }
  }
}
```

Apitest is declarative api testing tool with JSON-like DSL.

See https://github.com/sigoden/apitest