# Play Framework (Java) - Test multi part upload

Tags: upload, multipartform-data, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to test a multipartform upload to a controller, but I'm not able to figure out how.

I don't know which type of Fake request body I should create. Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Duplicate of [Test MultipartFormData in Play 2.0 FakeRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890381/test-multipartformdata-in-play-2-0-fakerequest)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I've searched, there is no clean way to do this in Java, however you can do it using scala.
see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890381/test-multipartformdata-in-play-2-0-fakerequest)